# Why Java SIM card secure channel returns "do not match"?

Tags: security, channel, javacard, gpshell

I'm trying to install an applet on a SIM card which supports java card V3.0.4. When I try to establish a secure channel to load the applet, the card returns an error:

```java
mode_211
enable_trace
establish_context
card_connect
select -AID A000000151000000
Command --> 00A4040008A000000151000000
Wrapped command --> 00A4040008A000000151000000
Response <-- 6F108408A000000151000000A5049F6501FF9000
open_sc -security 1 -keyind 0 -keyver 0 -mac_key 79AA24D80FF0056101F1D9AB6DCAF0E6
 -enc_key 79AA24D80FF0056101F1D9AB6DCAF0E6
Command --> 80CA006600
Wrapped command --> 80CA006600
Response <-- 664A734806072A864886FC6B01600B06092A864886FC6B020202630906072A86488
6FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B048000640B06092A864886FC6B040255640B06092A864886FC6B0
481079000
Command --> 8050000008F05E65BF5254BC9F00
Wrapped command --> 8050000008F05E65BF5254BC9F00
Response <-- 00005147A5190C5352322002001C1F47B6C76BABFD305EBBC2CD1BB39000
mutual_authentication() returns 0x8030F00A (The Secure Channel Protocol passed and reported do not match.)
```

I'm using GPShell-1.4.4. I guess the problem is using wrong key set! Am I true or there is something else I cannot guess what?!

Thanks for your response

Comment: Can you try `-keyDerivation` set to `visa2`? Almost all Gemalto SIMCards use this key derivation.

Comment: @Abraham tested, same result! is there any problem with the secure channel protocol? because I'm quite sure that the key is correct!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I am partly reusing an answer I wrote for your previous question which you suddenly deleted)

Error code [GP211_ERROR_INCONSISTENT_SCP](https://sourceforge.net/p/globalplatform/code/HEAD/tree/tags/globalplatform-6.0.0/src/globalplatform/errorcodes.h#l59) means that GPShell's intended SCP version mismatches with the real SCP version given by the card ([see here](https://sourceforge.net/p/globalplatform/code/HEAD/tree/tags/globalplatform-6.0.0/src/globalplatform.c#l3664)).

Check the 12th byte of card response to `INITIALIZE UPDATE` -- *Secure Channel Protocol identifier* (see e.g. [GP Card Specification 2.3](https://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp), section E5.1.6) and use parameter `-scp`.

Alternatively you might want to use [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) as GPShell is quite outdated...

**Beware that you can block your card by issuing multiple `INITIALIZE UPDATE` commands without successful authentication!**

---

As your current question contains the complete log it is possible to [parse](https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/?data=664A734806072A864886FC6B01600B06092A864886FC6B020202630906072A86488%0D%0A6FC6B03640B06092A864886FC6B048000640B06092A864886FC6B040255640B06092A864886FC6B0%0D%0A48107) the *Card Data* tag giving (according to [GP 2.2.1](https://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp)):

```
66 Card Data
    73 Card Recognition Data / Discretionary Data Objects
        06 OID
            2A864886FC6B01 {globalPlatform 1} // Card Recognition Data
        60 Application Tag 0
            06 OID
                2A864886FC6B020202 {globalPlatform 2 2 2} // GP 2.2 Card
        63 Application Tag 3
            06 OID
                2A864886FC6B03 {globalPlatform 3} // Card Identification Scheme
        64 Application Tag 4
            06 OID
                2A864886FC6B048000 {globalPlatform 4 128 0x00} // SCP80 i=0x00
        64 Application Tag 4
            06 OID
                2A864886FC6B040255 {globalPlatform 4 2 0x55} // SCP02 i=0x55
        64 Application Tag 4
            06 OID
                2A864886FC6B048107 {globalPlatform 4 129 0x07} // SCP81 i=0x07
```

So you might want to use `-scp 2 -scpimpl 0x55` or `-scp 2 -scpimpl 85` (which happens to be the same).

Or use [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro).

Alternatively `-scpimpl 0x15` should work as well as the *Well-known pseudo-random algorithm
(card challenge)* bit in 'i' should not matter...

Good luck!

Comment: dear vlp, Thank you for you exact and detailed response. I don't remember what was the question I deleted but I know there was a mistake  by myself which made that question wrong to ask. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It was [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630628/how-install-java-card-applet-on-sim-card)..I am glad the authentication works for you!

Comment: I undeleted and edited that question. Thank you vlp for your help. could you please put the answer in that question?

Comment: @MJay It makes no sense to answer the same question twice -- I think you should keep it deleted...Good luck with your project!